# How to build query form to request AWS CloudSearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I have a SearchDomain on AWS CloudSearch. I know all the defined facets names.

I would like to build a web query form to use it, but I want to add my categories values (facets) on the side, like it is done on Amazon webstore

The only way I have to get facets values is to make a query (params query) and in the answer will contain facets linked to my query results.

Is there a way to fetch all the **facet.FIELD** possible values to build the query form ?

If not (as read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856521/how-to-fetch-all-the-facets-from-cloudsearch)), how to design a form using facets ?

Comment: Finally I used a request with query="-ImpossibleTermInMyBase" and the facet options for every facet (**warning**, facets is also limited to 10 results, so, adjuste the facet option).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the matchall keyword in a structured query. Also, since you don't need the results you can pass size=0 so you only get the facets which will reduce latency.

```
/2013-01-01/search?q=matchall&q.parser=structured&size=0&facet.field={sort:'count',size:100}
```